# Find normal subgroups in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$

Tags: group-theory

I need to find all normal subgroups in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ = $G$. What I've reached:

1. $|G|$ = 24
2. This group has non-trivial center, $Z(G)$ = $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$, $Z(G) \triangleleft G$

I think that I can use Sylow theorem to reach this but I do not know where to begin.

Comment: FYI, $\LaTeX$ works in titles too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that the center of the group is always normal. I would then look at the Sylow groups (good thought there). The Sylow 3 subgroup is of order 3. Note that $\big\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix} \big\rangle$ is a subgroup of order three. But, $\big\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix} \big\rangle$ is also a cyclic three group distinct from the first one. So $SL_2(\mathbb{Z_3})$ does not have a normal Sylow-3 subgroup, as the two groups above are conjugate and distinct.

But, $\langle \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix} \rangle$ is a subgroup of order 8. It is a Sylow-2 subgroup therefore. It is not too hard to verify that this group is $Q_8$ (Quaternion group). One can then verify that this subgroup is in fact normal.

Comment: you can also note that the amount of $2$-Sylows is $n_2\equiv 1\pmod 2$ and $n_2|\frac{|G|}{2^3}=3$, so $n_2=1,3$.  Since you have already confirmed that there are  $4\ 3$-Sylows (there can only be $1$ or $4$), there are not enough elements for $3\ 2$-Sylows, so there can only be one $2$-Sylow, so it must be normal.